# Installing fingerprint reader on Dell Vostro

Tags: fingerprint-reader, dell-vostro

I followed few instructions for installing fingerprint reader on my Dell Vostro laptop, but with no success.

Fingerprint reader ID:

```
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 138a:0008 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS300 Fingerprint Reader
```

After running the command:

```
sudo fingerprint-gui
```

The GUI is opened, I click 'next' twice, I reach the following screen:

[image]

Then, one of two is happening:

1. The GUI is crashed with the following error:

   ```
   fingerprint-gui: drivers/vfs301_proto.c:102: usb_send: Assertion 'r == 0' failed.
   Aborted (core dumped)
   ```
2. I'm enrolling my finger with no response from the GUI.

Can you help me please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No one knows? Any suggestion?